# Django Docker timezone not working difference of 2 hours

Tags: python, django, docker

I am working on an application which is developed using django webframework, postgres database. for production I have dockerize the application and deployed it on linux system.
In the application I am using python datetime module to store the time of an event but there is problem that it has a time difference of 2 hours between the event and the value stored in the database. On debugging further I found that I need to give time-zone in my docker-compose.yml file. so I had added the following

```
environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Paris
```

On doing so the event time is coming correct on my local system but not on the linux machine. what could be wrong or what should I do so that the event time is correct. below is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=app
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASS=supersecretpassword
      - TZ=Europe/Paris
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=app
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword
```

Morover while debugging I have found that
on my local machine when I access python on the dockerize app and run following

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now())
```

then there in no time difference. But when I run same on the linux machine, dockerize app the time printed is 2 hours late from the current one

Comment: Did you set `USE_TZ = True` in the Django settings?

Comment: yes I have added this in the django settings

Comment: Does the Linux machine have the correct time?

Comment: yes, it does have correct time. as i run the following python script `from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now())` it does print the correct time